# How to create a npm library with only typescript model classes?

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

I am developing a large scale (multi-module, multi-repo) web application. All modules are being developed as separate Angular projects.

These Angular projects share some common ui components, services, and models, which I am publishing to npm (company maintained private npm repository - sinopia) and then install them in necessary modules.

I have used Angular libraries for ui components and services. Creating a whole new angular library project for models feels like a overkill since models contain class definition only (no logic).

Is there any framework or a common practise to develop these types of libraries?

(Link to a similar Git repository is highly appreciated)

Comment: So you just wanna expose interfaces/classes basically?

Comment: yes. that's exactly what I need to do using a npm package.

Answer (score 3):

Just some days back I had exactly same requirement where I need to refer classes and interfaces in multiple projects. You need to create node module which will be referred by all other projects.

Please refer my github repo https://github.com/Plochie/pacify.

This repo contains all classes in typescript and after building it you will get js files in dist folder. Please check `tsconfig.json` in each directory.